# Convert data back-and-forth between CSV files and pretty-print

Tags: haskell, csv, formatting

I wrote a script to convert CSV files in human readable format and vice versa.

Human readable format is achieved like so:

```
$ ./transform table.csv inflate
cola colb      colc
1    a         g
2    b         g
3    c         g
4    d         g
5    eeeeeeeee g
```

And conversion back to CSV is done with:

```
$ ./transformtable table.t
cola;colb;colc;
1;a;g;
2;b;g;
3;c;g;
4;d;g;
5;eeeeeeeee;g;
```

Code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split
import System.Environment
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  file <- readFile (args !! 0)
  let lp = preprocess (lines file)
  let erg = (if elem "inflate" args then (inflate) else (compress)) lp
  mapM_ putStrLn $ map concat erg

rpad len string = take len $ string++(repeat ' ')

--ensure last col has elements
preprocess lines = map (rpad len) lines
             where len = maximum $ map (length) lines

--calc lengths of the chunks(colname + spaces) for splitplaces
dissect line = zipWith (\a b->length (a++b)) names spaces
          where names = wordsBy (==' ') line
                spaces= wordsBy (/=' ') (line++" ") --add " " to ensure space after last col-name

compress lines = add_del $ transpose $ map (shrinkcol) cols
            where delim       = ';'
                  head_lens   = dissect (head lines)
                  cols        = transpose $ map (splitPlaces head_lens) lines
                  shrinkcol c = map (\el -> reverse $ dropWhile (==' ') $ reverse $ dropWhile (==' ') el) c
                  add_del     = map (map (++[delim]))

inflate lines = transpose $ map padcol $ table
          where table = transpose $ map (splitOn ";") lines --list of cols
                padcol c = map (rpad m) c --pad whole col
                   where m = (1+) $ maximum $ (map length) c --determine longest string in col, pad one more for prettiness
```

I'm relatively new to haskell, so I'm wondering if this can be done more elegantly.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Names

### Follow the Haskell convention of names

The Haskell convention is camelCase.  That is, start names with a
lowercase letter, and join words together by capitalizing them.  So
`head_lens` would be `headLens`, or better yet, `headerLengths`.

### Use names with meanings, not just labels

Come to think of it, an even better name would be `columnWidths`,
as that is not just what the value *is*, but what it *means* (and
what it is *used for*).  `lp` and `erg` don't tell me a lot,
either.  For `preprocess` I would suggest a name like `rightPadLines`.  That way, I won't be so surprised to find out what it does :)

### Don't be afraid of longer names

It is also useful and nice for other readers **not** to use
abbreviations, unless the scope is very small.  So the `a` and `b`
in `dissect line` are good and clear (very short scope -> very
short names).  `add_del`, on the other hand, would be more readable
as `addDelimiters`.  `delim` is a somewhat more conventional
abbreviation.

## Types

### Use the type system

Yes, Haskell can find out what types your values and functions
have.  And it will be correct in many, many cases.  But if *you*
are wrong, Haskell cannot tell you, unless you tell the compiler
what you intend to do.  So always, always write the type signatures
of at least the top-level bindings.  That way, if your function is
not yet finished, or you make a mistake, the compiler will be able
to tell you almost exactly where.

So:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do -- ..

rpad :: Int -> String -> String
rpad len string = take -- ..

preprocess :: [String] -> [String]
preprocess lines = map -- ..

dissect :: String -> [Int]

compress :: [String] -> [[String]]

inflate :: [String] -> [[String]]
```

Adding those type signatures alone, makes the function more
readable, because now I can expect what it is going to do.

## Use hlint on the code and heed warnings from ghc

Many warnings and suggestions are worthwile.  They can point out
possible mistakes or partial functions, but also show what an
idiomatic Haskell solution could be.  For instance:

### Use `head` instead of `(!!0)`

`readfile (args !! 0)` is reminiscent of other languages, where the
command line arguments are in an array, which you'd need to index.
Using the 0<sup>th</sup> index though, is normally done by using the `head`
function.  `readFile $ head args` is the suggested alternative.

### `elem` is more readable as `` `elem` ``

Functions that take more than one argument, can be inserted between
the first and second argument (infix) if you write backquotes
around them.  For many functions, such as `elem`, `mod` and `div`,
this makes much sense.  So `if elem "inflate" args` can be
rewritten as `` if "inflate" `elem` args ``.

### Redundant parentheses

In that same line, `(inflate)` and `(compress)` have parentheses
around them, but they are really not necessary.  Removing them
makes the line more readable (even for LISP programmers).

The same goes for `map (length) lines` in `preprocess`, `map (shrinkcol) cols` in `compress` and `(map length) c` in `inflate`.
And even `string++(repeat ' ')` can do without the parentheses.

### Shadowed bindings

Three functions use the name `lines` for a parameter, which happens
to be the name of a function, too.  It is best to heed this
warning, for two reasons:

1. If you happen to want to split some string later on in those
   functions, you'll have to change the name anyway.
2. People who see `lines` somewhere, will probably think of the
   function first, be confused, then remember that it is a
   redefined value.

Using `ls` is not that bad, by the way, especially if you change
the type to be more documentational (see below).

### Eta reduction

This mathematical term comes down to "remove the variable name", so
that the focus lies more on *what* the function does, and less of
what it functions *on*.  The function `shrinkcol` has a `c` on both
ends, and they can both be removed, resulting in:

```
shrinkcol = map (\el -> reverse $ dropWhile (==' ') $ reverse $ dropWhile (==' ') el)
```

Which expresses exactly the same, just in less "words".

### Avoid lambda

This warning, on the same function as above, suggests about the
same thing, but now for the `\el` variable.  However, because we
use the `$` for application of values, this line should be
rewritten using `.` for composition.  As `f . g` means: do `f`
after `g`, this comes mostly down to just replacing the `$` with
`.`:

```
shrinkcol = map (reverse . dropWhile (==' ') . reverse . dropWhile (==' '))
```

### Another composition opportunity

The last warning that ghc and hlint give us, is to use composition
in the `mapM_` call.  Instead of saying: "map `putStrLn` over the
result of mapping `concat` over the list `erg`, and combine that
into one `IO` action", you can say "map (`putStrLn` after `concat`)
over the list `erg`, and combine that into one `IO` action".  Which
is shorter in English already :)

```
mapM_ (putStrLn . concat) erg
```

And now we are warning-free!

## Types

### Use the type system

What, again?  Yes.  But this time, use it to document the intent of
the functions, not just the functionality.  The easiest way to do
this, is to declare simple type aliases.  For instance,
`preprocess` works on lists of `String`, but each `String` is
actually a `Line`.  So adding `type Line = String`, while it does
not give any added compiler safety (`Line` is just an alias, and
exactly the same as `String`), it does give a bit of documentation.

```
type Line = String
type Cell = String

preprocess :: [Line] -> [Line]

compress :: [Line] -> [[Cell]]

inflate :: [Line] -> [[Cell]]
```

Of course, making stronger types with constructors, using `data` is
even better, so that the type system helps you check whether the
code works, even before you run it.  Then, you can write functions
as transformations between types, instead of transformations
between "just `String`s".

Comment: Ah... `erg` is short for `ergebnis` (result)?

Comment: Er, yes, I forgot to translate that one...

Comment: No problem. Its purpose is clear :)